# How to configure kubernetes to allow for long running interactive sessions?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Having a problem here running `v1.5.1` using the `kubectl run/exec -i --tty` feature.

Connections do not get interrupted when data is being sent. So when I launch an interactive container session, with a script that outputs something every now and then, it seems to work.

Based on that, I created a **nasty workaround** to keep my container sessions going, without my interaction. It is really annoying that these sessions terminate prematurely. They leave garbage behind, that needs to cleaned up in case you are attaching to a running production container.

The workaround (print a space-character  to STDERR every 59 seconds as a background process):

```
# within your container session
$ while :; do sleep 59; echo -n ' ' >&2; done &
```

See the following output, when I do not launch such a script.
**It demonstrates that an interactive session terminates prematurely within ~ 2 minutes.**

This is really annoying if you are leveraging this functionality to debug running applications and container installations.

```
$ time kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
Waiting for pod default/busybox to be running, status is Pending, pod ready: false
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
Waiting for pod default/busybox to terminate, status is Running
error: timed out waiting for the condition

real    2m4.657s
```

*Re-post from this [Github Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15702#issuecomment-271551811).*

Comment: I think your problem is on the container level. Kubernetes itself does not pose any limitations there (I run sessions for days out of the box without problems).

Comment: I use a standard busybox, ubuntu or debian container. I have also net seen them dropping a shell or tty for no reason. Have you seen the Github issue? There was some faulty behaviour (connection timeouts) on the side of Kubernetes in the past.

Comment: Didn't have this problem in 1.3.X. Started in 1.4.X and still having it in 1.5.1. I'm using coreos - kube-aws, and the k8s api is behind a ELB.

Comment: Same here, running built on kube-aws with coreos and the API behind ELB. Maybe ELB is the traitor? Wonder how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by now.
The issue is caused by the Kubernetes API being served over an AWS LoadBalancer (ELB or ALB). Those kill connections after a timeout, leading to a disconnection between `kubectl` and the Kubernetes API server.

This is not a Kubernetes issue per se, it is related to how you serve the Kubernetes API server to the end user. In this case over a load balancer.

Quick woraround: Increase your timeout or send data over the wire once in a while to keep the connection open.